# C child process doesn't receive SIGINT signal

Tags: c, signals

I have some problem with processing signals.  I'm creating a simple web server, and  I don't understand why my initial process successfully catches and handles `SIGINT` signals, but the child processes it `fork()`s seem not to do so.  Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "thpool.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>

int asc;
threadpool thpool;

void sighand(int sig) { //function handler
    if (sig == SIGINT) {
        printf("ctr-c recived\n");
        go = 0;
        thpool_destroy(thpool);
        shutdown(asc, 2);
        close(asc);
        int a = 1;
        setsockopt(asc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &a, sizeof(int));
        exit(2);
}

void fun(void *client_socket) { 
    int sock = *(int*)client_socket;
    char buffer[1024]; 
    int n = read(sock, buffer, BUFFERSIZE);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}

int main() {
    int pid;

    if (signal(SIGINT, sighand) == SIG_ERR) //signal function
        perror("signal failed\n);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) { //new process
        int port = 8666, client_socket;
        struct sockaddr_in server, client;
        pthread_mutex_t M;
        pthread_mutex_init(&M,NULL);
        int parent = getppid();
        value = kill(parent, SIGTERM);  //kill the parent
        if (value == 0)
            printf("dead parent\n");
        else
            perror("errore");
        thpool = thpool_init(2); 

        //creazione socket
        asc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //new socket
        printf("\nsocket aperto\n");
        bzero((char *)&server, sizeof(server));

        //inizializzazione
        memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server.sin_port = htons(port);
        bind(asc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)
        printf("bind effettuata\n");
        listen(asc, 40) 
        printf("listen effettuata\n");
        printf("in attesa di connessione....\n");
        client_leng = sizeof(client);
        while (go) {
            if ((client_socket = accept(asc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_leng)) < 0) {
                perror("accept fallita");
                exit(0);
            } else {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&M);
                printf("accept effettuata\n");
                thpool_add_work(thpool, (void *)fun, (void *)&client_socket);
                puts("handler assigned\n");
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&M);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code that handles the signal? Providing a [mcve] means it more likely we'll be able to answer your question

Comment: ... and what, if anything, does the child actually do?  And how are you delivering the signal to it?  And are you sure you delivered the signal successfully? These sorts of questions are why we ask for an MCVE.

Comment: @Davide, when you say, signal handler is not invoked, which process did you mean , is it the child or the parent?

Comment: Child processes created via `fork()` do inherit their parents' signal dispositions.  If your experiment suggests otherwise to you then either the experiment is flawed or your interpretation of its results is flawed, but we can't tell you about the nature of the flaw is without more details.

Comment: i added my code. @John Bollinger isn't the SIGINT signal automatically delivered when i press ctrl-c?

Comment: @jsaji i mean the child process

Comment: That signal handler invokes undefined behavior by calling non-async-signal safe functions.  Per [footnote 188 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188):  "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  POSIX provides the ability to call async-signal-safe functions, but `printf()`, `setsocketopt()` and `exit()` are not safe to call in a signal handler, and anything named `thpool_destroy()` is certainly unsafe in a signal handler.

Comment: The code I see doesn't include the parent code which reputedly sends signals to the child process.  How are you launching this code?  Are you using the background operator `&` in the shell?  That has consequences… . Again, we need an MCVE (with, in your case, an emphasis on _complete_, meaning 'complete enough to be run', and with instructions on how the code is run and what inputs are fed to it (if any), and so on.

Comment: I am totally missing the point of the example `fork`ing at all.  The only thing the parent does is register a signal handler for `SIGINT`, and almost the first thing the child does is try to kill its parent (which is also unnecessary in its own right, as the parent could easily be allowed to terminate normally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: you are signaling a different process than you think you are.

You mention in comments that you are trying to deliver a `SIGINT` to your process by typing CTRL-C on the keyboard.  That's fine when you want to kill *the foreground process group* of the terminal then owning the keyboard.  Supposing that you launch your program from a shell window and it does nothing to put itself in the background, the initial process will indeed be in the foreground process group, and if you never `fork()` then nothing else you do do changes that until the process terminates.  Typing CTRL-C in that terminal will therefore deliver a `SIGINT` to that process.

HOWEVER, when the initial process dies, the shell that launched it puts itself back in the foreground.  You can check this by typing commands to it.  Moreover, in the case where the initial process successfully `fork()`s a child, the child and its process group move into the background when the when the shell puts itself in the foreground.  **At that point, any CTRL-C you type goes to the shell** (which ignores it), not to the child of your webserver process.

You can send a `SIGINT` to a process running in the background or without a controlling terminal via the `kill` command, for example

```
kill -INT 12345
```

If you use that method to deliver a `SIGINT` to the child process in your `fork`ing case, you will see that the process's registered signal handler catches and handles the signal exactly as it should.